# How to write a single responsibility principle

Tags: java, oop

I have menu class. Menu class provide links. Each link has IconId and text.
What class should create bitmap from IconId?
If Link class will build bitmap then it violates the SRP.
If helper class will build bitmap then it is Lazy Class.
Whats right?

```
public abstract class Link {
    private int iconId;
    private String description;

    /* getters */

    public abstract void action();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the scope of your design.

If all link classes will have the same bitmap type image, then it might make sense to place the image resolving mechanism within the abstract class itself.

If, on the other hand, you will have different image types and formats, then you would have to delegate the image resolution to the extending classes. So for instance, you could have `public class GifImageLink extends Link` and this class will take care of resolving the Gif image type, which in turn could be delegated to some other singleton class.